# Want to be certain that there is no way this decorative wall can be load bearing

Tags: walls, load, building

I am in a top floor flat, 2nd floor (G, 1 & 2) and have a decorative wall [Picture 1] separating the kitchen from the living area.

I just want to be certain it cannot be load bearing, or that any extra column etc needs to be built in the middle.

The wall is parallel to the joists and the beams on the ceiling appear to simply be there to hold the wall in place but they are bolted to the end of the middle joist [picture 2] .

I found a picture of the flat in the next block online, and it is open plan, doesn't look like they had to build a column [picture 4].

Just want to put my mind at ease.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a decorative wall?

Comment: Nobody can say there is "no way" but from the looks of it the wall is constructed 95% from trim and glass and in most places isn't even touching the ceiling let alone supporting it.  There are a couple of places, the right side of the door and the outside corner between the ladder and the drill, where there are what might be posts and there is some way they could be supporting.  The right side of the door in particular looks like it might be part of the perpendicular wall, that probably is structural if it is also perpendicular to the ceiling joists.

Comment: you have wiring in the wall. is it sturdy and hurt to kick it, or does it rattle/vibrate when kicked? You might not need the whole wall, but that king stud gives me pause about tearing it all out.